# Pulling Data into Crystal Reports from Epicor: Where is the data coming from?

Tags: crystal-reports, epicorerp

I am a novice with CR and have been given the task of writing my first report. I was given an example report from which to copy some of the formula logic and use as a starting point.

The first difference I am noticing is where we each pulled our data from, but I cannot tell where his is coming from, and unfortunately, he no longer works here.

His:

[image]

Mine:

[image]

I am retrieving my information from the "generate sample data" option in the BAQ Report Designer in Epicor, but am unsure of how he retrieved his data.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In Crystal Reports, go to Database > Set Datasource Location to see their datasource location.  It won't give you any necessary passwords, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables all of his files are located on his machine, which I would not have access to. Plus, they probably no longer exist. It looks as though he is pulling the information directly from the BAQ and skipping the Report Designer phase, but I'm not sure how that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, we were using different versions of CR.